# Livelink - OpenText : Call to rmclassifications to update status via API

Tags: opentext, livelink

Is there anyone who has succesfully implemented an API call to update the RM Status for a Node ?

I keep getting Bad Request when PUT-ting a request to this url:

https://myopentexturl/OTCS/CS.exe/api/v1/nodes/908816/rmclassifications

This is my request-body: (I received the RMMetadataToken boy doing a GET request).

```
class_id:258356
status:"MYCUSTOMSTATUS"
rm_metadataToken:MyRMMEtadataToken
status_date:20201106
secondary_class_ids:null
cycle_period:1
official:false
rsi:"7JR_2WKN_1" 
storage:"ELECTRONIC"
accession:null
subject:null
addressee:null
sent_to:null
originator:null
establishment:null
record_date:20200218
record_type:null
status_date:20200218
received_date:null
next_review_date:20201206
last_review_date:null
```

My response-Header:
OTCSTICKET: MyOtcsTicket

The above gives me a bad request every time

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a valid call. I tried the same with Postman and received the following. Maybe you can tryout Postman and see?

Bad request normally returning 500 and normally producing trace. Any clue in there, maybe?

[Postman LL Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji78v.png)

Comment: I tried in Postman, and got 400 Bad Request. This should indicate, if I read the docs correctly, that the node could not be found.:

https://developer.opentext.com/apis/a1cf71e9-0828-482f-a497-b2a02e1d80bb/Records%20Management%2021.1#operation/updateNodeById

But if I do a GET for that Node in Postman, just as your Postman Call, I get a valid response with JSON, just like you.

Answer (score 0):

For future references:

The documentation states all parameters are required, which is not. So i kept tring the call with a complete request, which failed over and over. Finally I tried using only the parameters I needed to update (STATUS) and the ClassID and rm_metadatatoken) and then I got a 200 OK.

It seems that this call updates the "rimsNodeClassification" table, which can only be updated with a status that is already configured in OT.